# String assignment to another string is by value or reference?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
string line1;
string line2;

line1 = "this";
line2 = line1;
line1.replace(0, 1, "T");
cout << "line1: " << line1 << "  line2: " << line2 << endl;
```

The output is:

```
line1: This line2: this
```

So it looks like line1 and line2 do not point at the same string object.

This is confusing for me, as I thought that since c++ strings are mutable, changing s1 should also change s2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects in C++ generally have value semantics.

That's because all the primitive types (such as `int`, `double`, `char`, etc.) work like that, and the types in the standard library (such as `std::string`, `std::vector`, `std::map`, etc.) were modeled after primitive types.

Thus:

```
string line1;
string line2;
```

means you have two entirely separate `string` objects. They're not references or pointers (like in e.g. Java), they are full objects themselves.

Then

```
line2 = line1;
```

does not mean `line2` refers to the same underlying object as `line1` (it cannot mean that because `line2` is not a reference or pointer); it means the contents of the `line1` object are copied into the `line2` object. Any later changes to `line1` are not visible in `line2` because it is an independent copy.

Comment: Thanks! Much of this goes over my head (just starting in c++), but I'll do some reading. Will this also be the case for classes I define myself or just for standard library types?

Comment: This is the case for classes you define as well, so long as you don't use pointers (you can see my above answer for details).

Comment: @titiree C++ is biased towards value semantics, so if you don't do anything special, your own classes will also behave like that. However, it is possible to create "handle" classes that only contain a pointer to some other object and then copying instances of your class just copies the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

They're mutable, but they're not references unless you declare them to be (and both were declared `string`, not `string&`). The line:

```
line2 = line1;
```

invokes copy assignment (had you declared and initialized it at the same time, it would have been copy construction, but there is no meaningful difference in this case), initializing `line2` to the same *value* as `line1`, but completely independent of `line1` from then on.